# No type was found that matches the controller name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I've got the infamous Web Api No type was found that matches the controller name. I had this web service working until we did a little restructuring of the file system and classes and now I'm getting this error. The File system sits as default with the Controllers and Models Folders while accessing a data class that comes from a class library inside the same solution. My routes haven't changed so I don't think that is an issue.

Here is my controller:

```
namespace CECC.Services.Controllers
{
    public class MeterBlinksController : ApiController
    {
        // Will return all the meters for the date range with blinks >= minimum blinks passed.
        public IEnumerable<JsonMeterBlinksModel> GetBlinks(string startDate, string endDate, int meterNumber)
        {
            return GetBlinksByDateRange();
        }

        public IEnumerable<JsonMeterBlinksModel> GetBlinksByDateRange()
        {
            var conn = new Connection();
            List<JsonMeterBlinksModel> blinksCollection = new List<JsonMeterBlinksModel>();

            string queryString =
                "select meteraccts.meternumber, t1.blinks, scemain.subname, feeder.feedername "
                + "from(select serialnumber, sum(blinkcount) as blinks "
                + "from cecc_processed_blinks "
                + "where trunc(blinkdate) between to_date(:startDate, 'dd-mm-yy') and to_date(:endDate, 'dd-mm-yy') group by serialnumber) t1 "
                + "left join meteraccts on t1.serialnumber = meteraccts.serialnumber "
                + "left join serialnumber on t1.serialnumber = serialnumber.serialnumber "
                + "left join scemain on serialnumber.subid = scemain.subid "
                + "left join feeder on serialnumber.subid = feeder.subid and serialnumber.fdrid = feeder.fdrid  "
                + "where METERNUMBER is not null and SUBNAME is not null and FEEDERNAME is not null and t1.blinks >= 0 order by t1.blinks desc";



            conn.QueryInto<JsonMeterBlinksModel>(ref blinksCollection, queryString, null);

            return blinksCollection;
        }
```

Here is my route:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

And at last, my error:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:36819/api/getblinks'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'getblinks'."}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This URL:

```
http://localhost:36819/api/getblinks
```

would be looking for a controller called `GetBLinksController`, which indeed can't be found.  I think you're looking to do this:

```
http://localhost:36819/api/meterblinks
```

You may also need to rename your `GetBlinks` method to simply `Get` to map to a default GET request:

```
public IEnumerable<JsonMeterBlinksModel> Get(string startDate, string endDate, int meterNumber)
{
    return GetBlinksByDateRange();
}
```

You *can* do "named" operations in a WebAPI controller, though I suspect you may need to add a route for that.  But by default it's going to look for verb-based operations (Get, Post, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Your request should be to /api/MeterBlinks of type GET

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are writing the wrong url. It should be `host and port + "/api/" + controller name + action name`. In your case would be :

```
//localhost:36819/api/MeterBlinks/GetBlinksByDateRange
```